# Using get_user in wordpress with sorting

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I have `wp_users` table which has a column ordering. I came to know that `get_users()` returns all the users.
I am using it like `get_users('orderby=ordering')`
I got help form [this link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users)

But unfortunately it is not sorting on ordering column.
Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first take a look at the users table from the database.
The command you try is good, but the argument you use for ordering might be wrong. You should order by a column from the users table, for example user name, or user id's..

On the link you mentioned I've found these:

orderby - Sort by 'ID', 'login', 'nicename', 'email', 'url', 'registered', 'display_name', or 'post_count'.

order - ASC (ascending) or DESC (descending).

Some working examples:

Get users by nicename:

```
$users = get_users('orderby=nicename');
```

Other examples:

Display users sorted by Post Count, Descending order

```
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( array ( 'orderby' => 'post_count', 'order' => 'DESC' ) );
```

Display users sorted by registered, Ascending order

```
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( array ( 'orderby' => 'registered', 'order' => 'ASC' ) );
```

Comment: really? take a look at this: http://codex.wordpress.org/images/9/9e/WP3.0-ERD.png

Comment: oh sorry, now I understand what you're asking. Maibe wordpress have some predefined functions that work such as: when you use get_users('orderby , they look after the columns defined in the image i attached, there is a possibility that wordpress can't use orderby to your new column.

Comment: please try orderby using a predefined column to see if it works, if for example it doesn't work for the id or nicename, then there is a problem with your wordpress, if it just don't work only for your new "ordering" column, then this is a wordpress possibly bug, or a "bad setting".

Comment: yes it seems it only work with predefined columns. Any other woay to make it work?

Comment: I really don't know this. I suggest you to go to the official wordpress forum and ask this question there. Hope you'll find a way to fix this problem.